# How do parameters work in C callback functions

Tags: c, callback

I'm reading some freeRTOS code, and I'm not understanding how a function callbacks work. Take this example. The following function is defined -

```
static void prov_event_handler(void *user_data,
                               wifi_prov_cb_event_t event, void *event_data)
{
    switch (event) {
        case WIFI_PROV_CRED_RECV: {
            wifi_sta_config_t *wifi_sta_cfg = (wifi_sta_config_t *)event_data;
            

...
            
}
```

This is the callback function that we want to call from this code:

```
/* Configuration for the provisioning manager */
wifi_prov_mgr_config_t config = {
    .scheme = wifi_prov_scheme_ble,
    .scheme_event_handler = WIFI_PROV_SCHEME_BLE_EVENT_HANDLER_FREE_BTDM,
    .app_event_handler = {
        .event_cb = prov_event_handler,
        .user_data = NULL
    }
};

ESP_ERROR_CHECK(wifi_prov_mgr_init(config));
```

So far, so good. Where I am confused is where the heck do the parameters come from? When `prov_event_handler` is run, it has values for event_data. How does this generally work?

Thanks.

Comment: Pointer to the structure containing the data is passed. Very simple

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Right I see. So the pointer to the callback is passed to wifi_prov_mgr_init inside the config struct. Inside this function, it generates all the parameters, and eventually calls the callback function (via the pointer it still has). I'd stop short of saying "Very simple",  but I think I've got it now.